# Use both -isystem and -I for the same path with CMake

Tags: c++11, cmake, dynamic-library

Is there a way to use both -isystem and -I on the same path in CMake? I am currently doing something like the following:

`add_library(lib SHARED libSource.cpp)
target_include_directories(lib PUBLIC pathA)
target_include_directories(lib SYSTEM PUBLIC pathA)`

When I run `make VERBOSE=1`, the build flags for `lib` only include `-isystem pathA`, where I need both `-isystem pathA` and `-IpathA`.

Answer (score 0):

> CMake allows [`generator expressions`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#manual:cmake-generator-expressions(7)), which you could use, for example:

**Output Expressions**:

These expressions generate output, in some cases depending on an input. These expressions may be combined with other expressions for information or logical comparison:

```
-I$<JOIN:$<TARGET_PROPERTY:INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>, -I>
```

Generates a string of the entries in the `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` target property with each entry preceded by `-I`. Note that a more-complete use in this situation would require first checking if the `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` property is non-empty:

```
$<$<BOOL:${prop}>:-I$<JOIN:${prop}, -I>>
```

Where `${prop}` refers to a helper variable:

```
set(prop "$<TARGET_PROPERTY:INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>")
```

↳ [CMake Generator Expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#manual:cmake-generator-expressions(7))

Comment: @I'L'I, thank you for the suggestion, but I do not need to output the expression for either my include_directories or my system_include_directories. I need to link them to 'lib'.

**Problem:**
When I add the system includes to the target, it removes the repeated directory that I need as part of the normal includes to the target. 

**Question:**
How do I avoid this, and have that same directory, 'pathA' as both a system include, with the '-isystem' flag, and a normal include, with the '-I' flag?